# Scientific form solution from sy.solve(polynomial equation)

Tags: python-3.x, scientific-notation

I am solving a sixth power polynomial equation using Sy.Solve(). It gives six roots, which are expected:

[-3.02703976426865 + 1.02362494266124e-30*I,
-1.89109045512392 - 3.08959762498395e-30*I,
-0.937528319407686 + 6.74463695496706e-30*I,
1.61752831940769 - 6.74463695496706e-30*I,
2.57109045512392 + 3.08959762498395e-30*I,
3.70703976426865 - 1.02362494266124e-30*I]

I have never seen such form before. I initially assume they are complex numbers but they are not. I found that I = 10 in python (when you type I, it returns 10), so e-10*I means 10^(-9). It seems really weird to me. Actually, their second parts are extremely small.

I need to use these solutions for next computation but I found such form can't be computed since all next solutions are with A + Be-C*I form.

**My question is how can I convert them to decimal forms?**

Btw, I have tried other root-seeking functions but I found solve() can generate multiple roots without worries since other root-seeking functions can only give one root.

I expect the result can only show normal number like
-3.02703976426865, etc.

The problem is that such scientific form can't be used for next calculations, for example
suppose
gamma_1 = -3.02703976426865 + 1.02362494266124e-30*I

Then if I want to compute the following
gamma_1*(gamma_1 - 1)
it gives me
Out[89]:
(2.70703976426865 - 1.02362494266124e-30*I)*(3.70703976426865 - 1.02362494266124e-30*I)